# ubuntu 18.04 workspace selector not properly rendered

Tags: workspaces, workspace-switcher

I recently updated my (gnome) Ubuntu from 17.04 to 18.04 and I got some problem with the workspace selector, the one shown at the same time (but on the opposite site) of the dock. It takes always the same size, independently from how many workspaces I selected but, more importantly, the highlighting border is almost always off-place and doesn't move. Here I am attaching a (link to a) picture:
[workspace selector issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDp0a.jpg)

Does anyone experience the same issue? Do you know of a way to fix it? I tried to change the number of workspaces but that is not able to trigger an "update" of the selector.

Thanks, bye

Aldo

UPDATE

I could track these messages in the syslog file (repeated many times for the same event):

```
gnome-shell[1714]: Object St.Bin (0x5568fd9cc030), has been already deallocated - impossible to access to it. This might be caused by the fact that the object has been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1714]: == Stack trace for context 0x5568fc367320 ==
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1714]: #0 0x7ffe004baa70 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspaceThumbnail.js:987 (0x7f61440f62b8 @ 439)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1714]: #1 0x7ffe004bb770 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7f61443b5de0 @ 71)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1714]: #2 0x5568fc714b98 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/workspaceThumbnail.js:897 (0x7f61440f4f78 @ 390)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1714]: #3 0x7ffe004bc360 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7f61443b5de0 @ 71)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1714]: #4 0x7ffe004bc420 b   self-hosted:915 (0x7f61443f12b8 @ 367)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1714]: #5 0x7ffe004bc510 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128 (0x7f61443d3230 @ 386)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1714]: #6 0x5568fc714b00 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/overview.js:568 (0x7f61442cf808 @ 324)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1714]: #7 0x7ffe004bd870 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7f61443b5de0 @ 71)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1714]: #8 0x5568fc714a80 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/overview.js:540 (0x7f61442cf780 @ 109)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1714]: #9 0x5568fc7149d8 i   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7f61443b5de0 @ 71)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1714]: #10 0x5568fc714958 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/overview.js:670 (0x7f61442cfab0 @ 71)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1714]: #11 0x5568fc7148b0 i   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7f61443b5de0 @ 71)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1714]: #12 0x5568fc714830 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/main.js:197 (0x7f61443da3c8 @ 39)
```

Comment: Indicate in your answer that you have an extension running to change the behaviour of the workspaces. The issue is due to the extension.

Answer (score 0):

I had 'similar' symptoms...  In my case the window manager crashed on login. You'll find the syslog at the bottom. My fix was to remove and re-install the offending shell extension. I do see that your syslog does not contain any local extension, so...your milage may vary.

```
gnome-shell[4825]: Some code accessed the property 'MAX_THUMBNAIL_SCALE' on the module 'workspaceThumbnail'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time being, but please fix your code anyway.
gnome-shell[4825]: Object St.Bin (0x55f40c455590), has been already deallocated - impossible to access it. This might be caused by the object having been destroyed from C code using something such as destroy(), dispose(), or remove() vfuncs
gnome-shell[4825]: Script <main> terminated with an uncatchable exception
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4825]: == Stack trace for context 0x55f40ae39340 ==
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4825]: #0 0x55f40b1e51b0 i   /home/niclas/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/workspace-grid@mathematical.coffee.gmail.com/extension.js:947 (0x7f243c5b4450 @ 275)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4825]: #1 0x55f40b1e5118 i   /home/niclas/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/workspace-grid@mathematical.coffee.gmail.com/extension.js:937 (0x7f243c5b43c8 @ 128)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4825]: #2 0x55f40b1e5070 i   /home/niclas/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/workspace-grid@mathematical.coffee.gmail.com/extension.js:1026 (0x7f243c5b4560 @ 164)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4825]: #3 0x55f40b1e4fd8 i   /home/niclas/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/workspace-grid@mathematical.coffee.gmail.com/extension.js:1264 (0x7f243c5b4bc0 @ 90)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4825]: #4 0x55f40b1e4f28 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:129 (0x7f245c65a1a8 @ 408)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4825]: #5 0x55f40b1e4e90 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:171 (0x7f245c65a2b8 @ 241)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4825]: #6 0x55f40b1e4e10 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:318 (0x7f245c65a9a0 @ 13)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4825]: #7 0x7fff0a24c040 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128 (0x7f24782d2230 @ 386)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4825]: #8 0x55f40b1e4d30 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/extensionUtils.js:191 (0x7f245c65e120 @ 459)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4825]: #9 0x7fff0a24ccb0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7f24782b5de0 @ 71)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4825]: #10 0x55f40b1e4ca0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/extensionUtils.js:197 (0x7f245c65e230 @ 28)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4825]: #11 0x7fff0a24d9b0 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/fileUtils.js:27 (0x7f245c65e340 @ 323)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4825]: #12 0x55f40b1e4c10 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/misc/extensionUtils.js:196 (0x7f245c65e1a8 @ 72)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4825]: #13 0x7fff0a24e610 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7f24782b5de0 @ 71)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4825]: #14 0x55f40b1e4b80 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:320 (0x7f245c65a918 @ 201)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4825]: #15 0x55f40b1e4b00 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:328 (0x7f245c65aa28 @ 36)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4825]: #16 0x55f40b1e4a80 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:359 (0x7f245c65ac48 @ 67)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4825]: #17 0x55f40b1e49f8 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:367 (0x7f245c65acd0 @ 41)
gnome-shell[4825]: Execution of main.js threw exception: Script <main> terminated with an uncatchable exception
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4825]: #18 0x55f40b1e4968 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/main.js:229 (0x7f24782da340 @ 1152)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4825]: #19 0x55f40b1e48e0 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/main.js:133 (0x7f24782da230 @ 237)
org.gnome.Shell.desktop[4825]: #20 0x55f40b1e4868 i   <main>:1 (0x7f2478286b38 @ 48)
gnome-session[4700]: gnome-session-binary[4700]: WARNING: App 'spice-vdagent.desktop' exited with code 1
gnome-session-binary[4700]: WARNING: App 'spice-vdagent.desktop' exited with code 1
```